# Maximum Profit given n apples to sell

Tags: algorithm, recursion, time-complexity

Given n apples to sell and an array of n integers 'price' such that price[i] denotes the price at which i+1 apples can be sold.Compute the maximum revenue that we can generate from selling n apples in any combination we may choose.

Example: Given 8 apples and the price array as follows:-

```
{1,5,8,9,10,17,17,20}
i.e.price of 1 apple = $1
total selling price of 2 apples = $5, etc.
```

The maximum revenue would be generated by selling 2 + 6 apples for a total of 5 + 17 = $22.

I have a simple recursive solution in mind but am wondering what is the best time complexity that we can achieve? Is there scope to apply Dynamic Programming or Memoization?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Definitions

Let `dp[k]` denotes the profit for selling `k` apples in the optimal way

Let `profit[k]` detones the profit for selling `k` apples at once.

### Recurrence relation

Clearly, `dp[0] = 0`.

Then we can define, a recurrence relation as follows:

`dp[k] = max{dp[i] + profit[k - i]}, where 0 <= i < k`

You are interested in computing `dp[n]`.

### Conclusion

You can easily implement it using bottom-up approach or memoization and both method are pretty straighforward.

The time complexity of this solution is `O(n^2)`, because computing a single entry in `dp` array takes `O(n)` time.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there scope to apply Dynamic Programming or Memoization?

Yes, your problem is similar to the [Rod-Cutting](https://www.google.com/search?q=rod%20cutting%20problem) problem, which is a famous example of dynamic programming.

> I have a simple recursive solution in mind but am wondering what is
>   the best time complexity that we can achieve?

The time complexity for the naïve apprach is`O(2^n)` while `O(n²)` using dynamic programming.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is pretty similar to the rod-cutting problem.So, the DP solution is
**P[i]=MAX(S<sub>i</sub>, k=1..i MAX(P[k]+P[i-k]))**

Max i=1 to n P[i] gives you the answer.
**S<sub>i</sub>**= price of i apples from the given array.
Running time: O(n)
Couldn't comment on previous comments yet since it requires level 50 and i have just joined.

Comment: Consider writing this as a comment to the accepted answer.